# Getting a clean installation of Windows 10 without installation media

Tags: windows-10, reset

Recently, I decided that I wanted to do a full wipe of all my stuff and return to a fresh Windows 10 installation. (with the anniversary update)

The laptop I am using originally came with Windows 8, so I fear that using Factory reset will cause me to downgrade all the way. I've noticed options to restore the computer and keep all your files, but that is not what I want to do. I do not have a restore point I can use to do this and I do not have a Windows 10 installation disk.

Is there a way I can blank slate installation of Windows 10 with the Anniversary Update installed?

Comment: Windows 10 Anniversary Update has two features that fullfill your requiresments.  The first is the Reset feature, and choosing the "keep nothing option, this will reinstall Windows 10 based on an image stored on your PC.  The other is the "refresh windows" which literally reinstalls your operating system.  Both options are in the same [menu](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-refresh-tool-do-clean-install-windows-10).  Several answers already exist on how to use the Reset feature within Windows 10, and the new feature isn't complicate to use, so it doesn't justify its own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet (IMO) is to get the Windows 10 installation media.

You can simply [download the media creation tool from MS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), use it to put the Windows 10 installer onto a USB key, boot from said USB key, and do a full reinstall.

Comment: As I point out, and the article I provided explains, Microsoft has integrated this suggestion into Windows.  You just use a different tool, other then Media Creation Tool, to install Windows.  It likely is the exact same tool, minus the ability to creation a installation disk, due to the look and feel of it being identical.