# Windows 10 won't load

Tags: windows-10, boot, troubleshooting, repair, reset

My computer (Windows 10) does not want to boot. It diagnoses and then tries to fix issues, but it loads for ages. I tried to make a bootable USB key to repair the computer (I downloaded a cracked copy since I do not have windows 10 cd since it was already on the computer, and I don't have a cd/dvd player on the PC), and nothing worked. I mean, I tried every single options in the troubleshooter, and even when I want to use a restore point (I have several restore points normally) it tells me that I don't have any. I also tried resetting the PC but keeping my files, and the PC tells me "The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again." Honestly it begins to bore me. Does anyone have a guess on this matter ? Thanks a lot and have a great day buddies. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a clean installation of Windows 10 without installation media](https://superuser.com/questions/1126847/getting-a-clean-installation-of-windows-10-without-installation-media)

Comment: That is not a duplicate, I do not want an installation, I want a repair :)

Comment: Why ? Can I keep my files ?

Comment: OK thank you very much. But the winRE doesn't seem to load without the USB key...

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) page, you can use the "Create Windows 10 installation media" button to build a bootable installer on your USB key, no cracking or hacking required. If you want something a bit more helpful, repair-wise, visit TenForums.com and the tutorial on Kyhi's rescue disk at https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk.html.

Comment: You should quote and cite your source.

Answer (score -2):

all you had/have to do is rebuild the MBR, and run chkdsk. Happened to me.

apparently ya'll don't believe me... hahaha nice joke.[image]

[image]

Comment: you all don't believe me...